# VueJs drop-down first item not selected on initial load

Tags: vuejs2

I have a drop-down option working with an array of items. I want to add the first selection/option as **Select a Site**.

When the element is rendered, the drop-down does not show the **Select a Site** initially. The drop-down element does have the array in the drop-down options.

[image]

- The first image shows the initial state of the drop-down (looks
  empty, but its not)

[image]

- The second image is when the drop-down element is
  when selected.

How can I the drop-down working with the *Select a Site* shown as the first option?

```
<select id="ddSite" name="ddSite" class="form-control m-b-10" v-on:change="onChangeSite($event)" v-model="ddSite">
    <option :value="null">-- Select a Site --</option>
    <option v-for="option in sites" v-bind:value="option.SiteId">
        {{ option.SiteName }}
    </option>
</select>




new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            sites: [],
            ddSite:""
        },
        mounted() {
            axios.get("/api/sites/" + this.companyid)
                .then(response => {
                    this.sites = response.data
                });
        },
        methods: {
            onChangeSite: function (e) {
                var self = this;
                var siteid = e.target.value;
                var sitename = e.target.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].text;
            },
```

Comment: Can you show your data object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you're binding the select's value to `ddSite`.

The `-- Select a Site --` option has a value of `null`, but your `ddSite` data starts off as an empty string.

In order to have that option selected initially, you must init `ddSite` as `null`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    ddSite: null,
    sites: [{
        SiteId: 1,
        SiteName: 'Google',
      },
      {
        SiteId: 2,
        SiteName: 'Facebook',
      },
      {
        SiteId: 3,
        SiteName: 'StackOverflow',
      },
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select id="ddSite" name="ddSite" v-model="ddSite">
    <option :value="null">-- Select a Site --</option>
    <option v-for="option in sites" :value="option.SiteId">
      {{ option.SiteName }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: The ```ddSite: null``` made the difference!  Thanks